# getting points of Bezier Curve after moving that particular object

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, bezier

I have a curve which is drawn by using Bezier curve. Now i am moving this particular object and placing it in another location. How can i get the new points for the curve of that object.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    [myPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 400)];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(400, 400)];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(400, 100)];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];


    [myPath closePath];
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

This is my code to draw the rectangle. Now by using touches i am moving the rectangle, after moving how can i get the new points of the rectangle.In this particular case i am using a rectangle but there may be a polygon of indefinite points, in that case how can i get those points.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple linear transformation you only need to apply `dx` and `dy` to each control point of your curve (aka add your change in x and y to all the points you defined for the curve).